# Consider a bool in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

This should be some easy points for someone I expect, but as a Front End developer trying to get to grips with MVC razor with zero prior knowledge of C# this has me stumped.

I have a boolean var `hasSecond` which I would would like to consider in the following `foreach`:

```
@foreach (PODO_AcceptRejectReasons reason in reasonList2.Where(e => e.Type == 1))
    {
        <option data-confirm-type="1" data-confirm-attr="@reason.Attribute" value="@reason.ID">@reason.Text</option>
    }
```

I only want to display an option with a `@reason.Atrribute` value of 'SECOND' when `hasSecond` is `true`, otherwise do not display these options.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@foreach (PODO_AcceptRejectReasons reason in reasonList2.Where(e => e.Type == 1))
    {
        if(hasSecond||reason.Attribute!="SECOND")
        {
            <option data-confirm-type="1" data-confirm-attr="@reason.Attribute" value="@reason.ID">@reason.Text</option>
        }
    }
```

Should do the trick. I think I had the logic slightly wrong before. This will display all `option`s where `reason.Attribute` isn't `SECOND`. If it *is* `SECOND`, it will only show the `option` if `hasSecond` is true.

Answer (score 1):

just add it to the Where statement:

```
@foreach (PODO_AcceptRejectReasons reason in reasonList2.Where(e => e.Type == 1 && hasSecond))
    {
        <option data-confirm-type="1" data-confirm-attr="@reason.Attribute"   value="@reason.ID">@reason.Text</option>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way, just put an if statement in the foreach loop and add another clause to the where.

```
@foreach (PODO_AcceptRejectReasons reason in reasonList2.Where(e => e.Type == 1 && e.Attribute=="SECOND"))
{
    if(hasSecond)
    {
        <option data-confirm-type="1" data-confirm-attr="@reason.Attribute" value="@reason.ID">@reason.Text</option>
    }
}
```

If you just want the `data-confirm-attr="@reason.Attribute"` removed if `hasSecond` is false, the you can use the following:

```
@foreach (PODO_AcceptRejectReasons reason in reasonList2.Where(e => e.Type == 1))
{
    <option data-confirm-type="1" @if(hasSecond) { <text>data-confirm-attr="@reason.Attribute"</text> } value="@reason.ID">@reason.Text</option>
}
```

Comment: I think there's more required to the conditional than just `hasSecond` - otherwise, why place it *inside* the `foreach`?